# Angular 14 ngFor not workin on API call. Nothing to show

Tags: angular

Following is my Component:

```
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {

  userList$:any;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.userList$ = []
  }

  initUserList() {

    this.httpClient.get("https://localhost:44447/api/User/GetUserList").subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.userList$ = res.resultObject;
      console.log(res.resultObject)
    })

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initUserList()
  }

}
```

Following is my Template:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of userList$">
  {{user.fullName}}
</div>
```

The response returned from the service is written to the userList object. Console output as below

[image]

The response returned from the service is written to the userList object. But for some reason the template is not updating

Comment: Did you set your component to use `OnPush` change detection strategy?

Comment: Have you verified the array elements contain the `fullName` property? (*maybe `<div>` are being rendered with no content*)

Comment: yes fullName property exists on objects

Comment: I tried the OnPush change detection strategy now but it didn't work

Comment: Yes, `OnPush` will not work in this case, if you still have it enabled, try removing it.

Comment: If that's not the problem, see if you can reproduce in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular-ivy)

Comment: I'm not familiar with using $ in variable names. have you tried it without the dollar sign? as a debugging step, add this to your html: `<div>{{userList$}}</div>` just to see if something is getting populated.

Comment: Could you show me the console result please?

Comment: The response from the service is as follows {
  "result": 0,
  "resultMessage": "",
  "resultObject": [
    {
      "id": "aeb35aaa-8f7d-4b80-a644-4a8577b86c5d",
      "username": "eminuzn",
      "fullName": "Emin Uzun",
      "password": "123456",
      "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
    },
    {
      "id": "958a633c-aeb8-4741-9545-e14335a9c073",
      "username": "test",
      "fullName": "test123",
      "password": "123456",
      "email": "asd@gmail.com",
    }
  ]
}

Comment: @Rick I removed the $ sign and added <div>{{userList}}</div> to the html. Nothing has changed, I can't get any output on the screen

Comment: @BizzyBob In my experiment on StackBlitz, I can print the service results to the screen, but not in my own example.

Comment: I solved the problem, after syncing the service response to the variable, writing the code this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges() detected the changes.But do I have to write this every time? Shouldn't it auto-detect?

Comment: I'm not an expert at this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges, but you probably want to do that any time you are updating a global variable that is inside a promise.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've been struggling with this for hours :D

Comment: Typescript is typed for a reason. "Any" is your enemy. userList$ should be an observable whose result is handled async.

Comment: NOTE: the sufix `$` is used generally when we have an observable (but **nobody** prevent us form using this, althought it's considered a "good practice" use it only when the variable is an Observable). About the question use `{{user|json}}` to see really the properties or user, then change the "userName" by a property.